# Angular - How to add or use search filter pipe in template file

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I am trying to learn angular and i am stuck with a small problem. I want to add search filter in my table. For table i am using material angular. I don't know or you can say i have no knowledge about how and where i use pipe filter in tempelate file. Below are my source code files.

filter.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'productfilter'
})
export class ProductfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value:any,searchTerm:any): any {
    return value.filter(function(searchelement){
      return searchelement.name.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1
    })
    
  }

}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  searchedResult:string="";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

tempelate file:

```
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Elements</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="search element here..." [(ngModel)]="searchedResult">
    </mat-form-field>

  
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Please provide me solution where i add pipe filter in tempelate file. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts Refer to this stackblitz example.

Comment: if you are determined to use pipe here you have an article https://www.codementor.io/@chintankotadiya/angular-4-6-filter-search-custom-pipe-td46o91qg